# Display results of Android unit tests in Jenkins?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, jenkins-plugins

Android Studio and Android Gradle Plugin v1.1 provide some basic support for unit testing in Android:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

I have it working on a Jenkins CI server and it works well, but I'd prefer to see the test results displayed in an easier to read form than trawling through the console output.

Ideally I'd like to display the results using a Jenkins plugin like this:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin

Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: I use maven plugin not gradle. I can help about that .?

Comment: No thanks, I need a solution for Gradle builds.